# Is it possible to get a hook into external storage being mounted?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

External storage can be dismounted from Android. Is it possible to get an API hook so some custom code can be called when new storage is made available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have googled this a little more. I was looking for `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED